# Read data from json object in reactjs showing error

Tags: reactjs

I have facing a problem with getting data from json object with react. Here is my example data:

```
const data = [
{
  "name": "Adele",
  "age": "17",
  "exampleValue": "Dummy"
},
{
  "name": "Adele",
  "age": "17"
}

]
```

But when i'm trying to get data from the object with "exampleValue". it showing me error.

Is there any way to solve it without adding "exampleValue" in second object?

Comment: Please provide the code where you actually facing an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the elements which may present in the node can be read by adding certain condition. Like in your cases you can check if the element in the json node present or not using "hasOwnProperty"

Example

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([{
  "name": "Adele",
  "age": "17",
  "exampleValue": "Dummy"
},
{
  "name": "Adele",
  "age": "17"
},
{
  "name": "Adele",
  "age": "17",
  "exampleValue": "User"
}]);

const renderRow=()=>{
  return arr.map((item, index)=>
  <div style={{fontSize:18}}>
    {item.hasOwnProperty("exampleValue")? item.exampleValue:null}
  </div>
  )
}

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {renderRow()}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

Working example: https://snack.expo.dev/L_a4aNEL1